# Map Differently in Different Circumstances

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

We map out entities to models for our API. When an entity is a child of another entity, we general use a generic model for it that only has the display name and id. What I'd like to do is map that display name differently if the entity is a child of a certain type vs another. Is there any way to do this besides creating a new generic model specifically for this purpose?

### Entity Examples

```
CompanyName {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

Contact {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    int? CompanyNameId { get; set; }
    CompanyName CompanyName { get; set; }
    string DisplayName { get {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}{2}", FirstName, LastName, CompanyName != null ? string.Format(" - {0}", CompanyName.Name) : string.Empty);
    } }
}

Employee {
    int Id { get; set; }
    int ContactId { get; set; }
    Contact Contact { get; set; }
}
```

### Model Examples

```
CompanyNameModel {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

ContactModel {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    int? CompanyNameId { get; set; }
    CompanyNameModel CompanyName { get; set; }
    string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

EmployeeModel {
    int Id { get; set; }
    int ContactId { get; set; }
    //XSModel Contact { get; set; } // What I'm trying to use
    XSContactNoCompanyModel Contact { get; set; }
}

XSModel {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

XSContactNoCompanyModel : XSModel { }
```

### Map Registration Examples

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CompanyName, CompanyNameModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<CompanyName, XSModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Contact, ContactModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Contact, XSModel>();
// This is my current workaround, but I'd like to get away with less models if possible.
Mapper.CreateMap<Contact, XSContactNoCompanyModel>().ForMember(x => x.DisplayName, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.FirstName + ' ' + y.LastName));
Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeModel>();

// What I'm trying to do:
//Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeModel>().ForMember(x => x.Contact.DisplayName, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Contact.FirstName + ' ' + y.Contact.LastName));
// This errors with 'Expression must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AfterMap` (or `BeforeMap`) to accomplish things like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeModel()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Contact.DisplayName, config => config.Ignore())
    .AfterMap((src, dest) => 
        dest.Contact.DisplayName = src.Contact.FirstName + " " + src.Contact.LastName);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to configure a child property, that's not how AutoMapper works. When you create maps, you're configuring members of the destination type, not child objects.

Your statement "I'd like to get away with fewer models".

Don't. Create models for specific situations for specific configurations. That's the whole point. Name the destination types according to those situations and configurations. Adding additional destination model types is not a significant cost, but having complicated configuration is a mental cost.

Answer (score 0):

You can use projections to customize your mapping for a certain members:

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Projection

Comment: I tried this initially but because the mapping I was trying to do was on a child it would not work. Specifically, it gave me the error "Expression must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties."

Comment: Could you post some example code - it's hard for me to understand what you're trying to do exactly.

Comment: Added to the original post.

Comment: Do the other answers help?